# Is it faster to run one process that spawns N threads or to run N processes?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I realize that this will largely depend on the processes in question, but is there a rule of thumb?

Say I have a multi-threaded program called `progX` that offers a command line switch (`--cpu`) controlling the number of CPUs it can use. Is it faster to launch 40 parallel instances using one CPU each (`progX --cpu 1`) or to launch a single instance, telling it to use 40 CPUs (`progX --cpu 40`)?

Comment: Are we talking about a particular OS here?

Comment: Performance will probably depend on the OS. But the semantics are very different, especially if you need to share information across your threads/processes.

Comment: Well, the reason I asked is because I have ~1500 `blastpgp` jobs to run on Linux. It just got me curious as to a general rule, if any. Could you expand a bit on why the OS is important?

Comment: If the application is well designed, telling it to use all CPUs should be fastest (as it should internally create processes or threads according to whatever is most efficient). Under linux, processes are free to call pthread_create() or fork() as they see fit, and retain control over all created children. In Windows, forking is a lot more messy.

Comment: @tucuxi, thanks, not worried about windows, I only ever use it for games.

Comment: Well, thank you all for your answers. Since you are all making essentially the same point, I will accept the answer of @canolucas who needs the rep more than the others :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is faster to lauch a single instance by far. Threads are made for that purpose, and they are lighter that processes. The de-facto rule is: let the OS do the scheduling and memory management unless you need to do the dirty job by yourself. This way your code will be much simpler and cleaner. The OS has a bunch of lower level tools to handle processes and memory much more efficiently. Of course it will depend on the OS, but this is a general rule for modern OS, and at least the one i use (Linux).

Comment: So, what you are saying is that the two methods are equivalent and what makes the multi-thread choice faster is that it will create a lesser load for the server correct?

Comment: actually what i'm trying to say is that the general rule is: "a single instance is better", instead of creating N processes create the threads you need, and let the OS handle processes.

Answer (score 2):

Largely depends on the OS, but in general threads are more lightweight than processes (in fact each process is composed of at least one thread) so by starting one process with 40 threads you'll put less pressure (especially with regards to memory consumption) on the system.

Also remember that threads are fundamentally different than processes as they operate on shared address space. But it's irrelevant if you they communicate with each other.

Comment: Thanks, I can understand that. What if system load is not an issue and all I care about is finishing my jobs _fast_? Which of the two would you expect to be faster on a linux system?

Comment: @terdon: if there is a high startup cost (like in Java), it might be faster to start only one process rather than paying startup costs 40 times.

Comment: Tomasz, you may also be interested in lowering their priority, so they take precedence over other jobs in the system. Look up the `nice` command.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is : without any relations between your tasks the performance of the multi-process version will tend to the one of the multi-threaded version (some OS implements threads with processes so performance will be strictly equivalent).

You'll pay more to initialize your process, especially if you're using some hosting environment (e.g. Java or .Net) but over-time this initial startup fees will become negligible.

So if you have small tasks difference could be huge but if you run your tasks during hours it will be negligible.

Things become interesting when there is some interaction between your threads :

- **shared data** : sharing memory between process is more involved and costly than between threads
- **synchronization** : synchronizing processes is too more cumbersome especially if you can use language construct for transparent thread-synchronization

Performance is not a good fit for multi-process, but there is other good reasons to use it like **reliability** : if you use some component that may break and crash the process, if you have a multi-threaded application a failure will cause the loss of all your tasks whereas with a multi-process application only one will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The most precise answer is to take a smallish task and time your application with a variety of settings. You can launch N processes of M cpus each via

```
#!/bin/bash
M=$1
N=$2
for ((i=0; i<$N; i++)) ; do ( echo $i && time progX --cpu $M & ) ; done
```

The important time is the last one printed (all processes should start in parallel more or less at the same time).

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but I was wondering if there is a general rule. The gist of all the answers is that essentially the two choices are equivalent, and what changes is the greater system load when running multiple processes. Is that correct?

Comment: Not really - but it depends on so many things, that even though "keep it light" (and therefore, threads) will usually work, testing things out is the only way to get a true answer.